# How to use configuration in scala play 2.5.8 in an object

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.5

I am migrating from play `2.4.x` to play `2.5.8`

While migrating I am getting a lot of deprecation related warning that I am trying to resolve. Once such error is method current in object Play is deprecated: This is a static reference to application, use DI instead

below is the object

```
object Foo{
  def testURL= {
   val test =  Play.current.configuration.getString("test.url")
}
```

If I try to use `config = Configuration.load()`  I get the error overloaded method value load with alternatives:

> (environment: play.api.Environment)play.api.Configuration 
>   (environment: play.api.Environment,devSettings:
>   Map[String,AnyRef])play.api.Configuration cannot be applied to ()

I there a way to use the `play.api.configuration` here ? I don't want to convert object into singleton class.

Answer (score 3):

I'm basing this answer on [this group post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/6Pec5if3FEE) because it's about as good an answer as you'll get for this topic.

What you're trying to do is an anti-pattern, because something is an object it should not depend on external state.  Technically, configuration is based on the state of a file on the filesystem, so it is state in that sense.

To do this cleanly, you should use a class.